How to submit array of jobs using TORQUE/PBS but using predefined list of nodes or exclude some nodes?
I want to submit a job array to TORQUE, but I really want to run these jobs only on the specific nodes (I have a list of nodes to exclude from using). How to do this?
here is my initial sh script to submit a job array..
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N F3
#PBS -V
#PBS -q fill

# old code to require any node...
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
    
#PBS -t 0-499%25
#PBS -o "out_errors/outputs/o_"
#PBS -e "out_errors/errors/e_"

# Limit computational time
#PBS -l walltime=150:00:00

I have tried this code:
#### try to get node for the job from a list of nodes
#PBS -l nodes=c0307+c0701+c0504+c0306:ppn=1  # 

but I have got all the jobs in status Q - and nothing is running.. It seems like this directive requires all of this nodes for one job, while I want at least one of this nodes..
Really - for me it will be easier to exclude specific nodes but it seems that is quite tricky (there is no direct ways of doing this). Or am I wrong?
